# What does omnifaces JNDI.lookup not have a checked exception for NamingException?

Tags: jsf, glassfish, jndi, omnifaces

I replaced all of my JNDI lookups with JNDI.lookup() method because it seemed convenient, dealt with dynamic return types, etc.  All was great...but now I just noticed that the checked exceptions that I had to catch before are no longer there.

I assumed this was because it would have just returned null if the JNDI variable didn't exist but it doesn't.  It now just throws an unchecked exception.

Any idea why?  Is there a way of just returning null for non-existant variables instead?

I created a bug for this on the omnifaces website:  https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/141

Not sure if this is intended behavior or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way of just returning null for non-existant variables instead?*

It does that for `NameNotFoundException`. The problem was here not in OmniFaces, but in the environment, which was GlassFish 4.1 in your specific case. It unexpectedly wrapped the `NameNotFoundException` in another `NamingException`, hereby causing the underlying `NameNotFoundException` to slip through and bypass the `return null` condition.

This has been fixed with help of [`Exceptions#is()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Exceptions.html#is-java.lang.Throwable-java.lang.Class-) utility method as per [this comment](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/ff948cb4126ac70d26f5ea54dda5b2a65de2b163). It will be available in OmniFaces 2.2.